# sort csv with new lines

Tags: powershell, csv, sorting, format

I got my report with users and workstations. Now if a User has several workstations I want to have a separate line for each of his workstations. Always with Name, Surename, Workstation. At the end it should be exported as a report-new.csv.

**CSV:**

```
"Name","Surname","Workstation"
"John","Doe","PC001,PC005,PC100"
"Fonzarelli","Arthur","PC234,PC324"
"Tribbiani","Joey","PC999"
```

**Script:**

```
$report = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\report.csv"

Foreach ($wst in $report) {

    If ($wst.Workstation -match ",") {

        New Line foreach Workstation? Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\report-new.csv" -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Report | ForEach {ForEach ($ws in ($_.workstation -split ",")) {
    $_ | Select Name, SurName, @{Name = "Workstation"; Expression = {$ws}}}
} | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\report-new.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Result:

```
Name       Surname Workstation
----       ------- -----------
John       Doe     PC001
John       Doe     PC005
John       Doe     PC100
Fonzarelli Arthur  PC234
Fonzarelli Arthur  PC324
Tribbiani  Joey    PC999
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *split* the `Workstation` property by a comma and *join* it together using a newline. Example:

```
$report = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\report.csv"

Foreach ($wst in $report) {

    ($wst.Workstation -split ',') -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint Martin. I just edit my question. It should always have the same scheme: Name, Surename, Workstation. And an export at the end.

Comment: If you want to export it back to CSV, you can't put each workstation to a new line because a new line represents an new record in csv.